# Power Series Representation Problem

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am having a hard time understanding how to proceed with this question. I am trying to find a power series representation, as well as the interval of convergence.

$$f(x)=\frac{8x^3}{(7x+8)^2}$$

I started out by rearranging the equation into

$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{8}\frac{1}{(1-(\frac{-7x}{8}))^2} $$

Then I plan to transform the equation like

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$$

I got stumbled on this step as I am not sure about cn. Is it -7/8?

Any help will appreciate!

Comment: What value is this centered around? I assume $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your rearrangement is correct.

$$ \operatorname{f}(x)=\frac{x^3}{8}\frac{1}{(1-(-\frac{7}{8}x))^2}$$

Then we represent $\operatorname{f}(x)$ by 2 parts:
$$ \operatorname{f}(x)=\frac{x^3}{8}\operatorname{g}(x)$$

$$\operatorname{g}(x)=\frac{1}{(1-(-\frac{7}{8}x))^2}$$

Integrate $\operatorname{g}(x)$ on both sides.

$$\begin{align}
\int \operatorname{g}(x) \operatorname{d}x &=-\frac{8}{7}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{7}{8}x)}\\
&=-\frac{8}{7}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-\frac{7}{8}x)^n
\end{align}$$

Now take the derivative of both sides.

$$\operatorname{g}(x)=-\frac{8}{7}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-\frac{7}{8}n(-\frac{7}{8}x)^{n-1}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{f}(x)&=\frac{x^3}{8}\big(-\frac{8}{7}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-\frac{7}{8}n(-\frac{7}{8}x)^{n-1}\big)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{8}(-\frac{7}{8})^{n-1}x^{n+2}
\end{align}$$

The radius of convergent interval $R$ is:

$$\begin{align}
R&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{n}{8}(-\frac{7}{8})^{n-1}}{\frac{n+1}{8}(-\frac{7}{8})^{n}}\right|\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{n}{(-\frac{7}{8})(n+1)}\right|\\
&=\frac{8}{7}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $(-\frac{8}{7},\frac{8}{7})$ is in the convergent interval. Now check $\operatorname{f}(-\frac{8}{7})$ and $\operatorname{f}(\frac{8}{7})$.

$$
\operatorname{f}(-\frac{8}{7})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{8}(-\frac{7}{8})^{3}\\
$$

$\operatorname{f}(-\frac{8}{7})$ must be divergent since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n$ diverges.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{f}(\frac{8}{7})&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n}{8}(\frac{7}{8})^{3}\\
\end{align}$$

$\operatorname{f}(\frac{8}{7})$ must be divergent since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} n$ diverges.

To sum up, the convergent interval is $(-\frac{8}{7},\frac{8}{7})$.

Answer (score 0):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(x)}
> &=\frac{x^3}{8}\frac{1}{\left(1-\left(\frac{-7x}{8}\right)\right)^2}
> =\frac{x^3}{8}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{7x}{8}\right)^2}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{x^3}{8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{n}\left(\frac{7x}{8}\right)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\left(-\frac{7}{8}\right)^nx^{n+3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(n-2)\left(-\frac{7}{8}\right)^{n-3}x^{n}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude from (3)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{
> c_n=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{8}(n-2)\left(-\frac{7}{8}\right)^{n-3}&\qquad n\geq 3\\
> 0&\qquad \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> }
> \end{align*}
> From (1) we recall  the binomial series is convergent for
> \begin{align*}
> \left|\frac{7x}{8}\right|<1\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \color{blue}{|x|<\frac{8}{7}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we make a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-2}{n}=\binom{n+1}{n}(-1)^n=(n+1)(-1)^n$.